# c++ overloading operator stack overflow

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the `[]` operator. I am getting an unhandled exception error. I am implementing a matrix class using a `vector<double>`.

```
double& Matrix::operator[](int i) 
{
    return (*this)[i];
}
```

Comment: Explain what this does to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): `(*this)[i]`.

Comment: Looks like a recursion.

Comment: Shouldn't matrices have more than one dimension?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, not necessarily, a 1xN or Nx1 matrix is still a matrix. As a matter of fact, a 0x0 matrix is valid too.

Comment: I probably should delete this question. -3 within two mins

Comment: The solution is obvious immediately once you read the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258079).

Comment: return (*this)[i]; calls the operator[] of Matrix and that call will call its operator[] again. thats an infinite recursion!!! you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That's like saying that vectors should have more than one element.

Comment: @Singer, Kerrek, okay, I stand corrected, there are indeed uses for row or column vectors (as Wikipedia calls them). I never used them myself, 's all :)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall 1xN is two dimensional where the rank of the first dimension is 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions

Comment: Also, a debugger would probably have pointed you at the problem quite easily, either through the backtrace or by letting you step through the execution.

Comment: @DoubleOseven _"I probably should delete this question. -3 within two mins"_ Unfortunately you can't now anymore, since it has an upvoted answer. Let us do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(*this)` returns your `Matrix` object.  Therefore, `(*this)[i]` calls `Matrix::operator[](i)`.  Your function is calling itself without any terminating conditions, similar to this:

```
int foo() {
    return foo();
}
```

Which, as you can imagine, will crash pretty quickly.

You probably want to call `std::vector::operator[]` from a member variable.  For example, if your class has a private vector object called `vec`, you might want to do:

```
double& Matrix::operator[](int i) 
{
    return this->vec[i];
}
```

Also, `this->member` is shorthand for `(*this).member`, use it more often!

Answer (score 1):

`(*this)[i]` is functionally equivalent to `(*this).operator[](i)`.

It therefore calls `Matrix::operator[](i)`.  Since that happens within the operator function itself, the function unconditionally calls itself recursively.   This means it will keep calling itself until memory is exhausted, which - on some systems - results in a system exception.

Assuming `Matrix` has a member of type `std::vector<double>`, you probably need to use `that_member[i]` (which calls the vector's `operator[]`) rather than `(*this)[i]`.